# Verilog doesn't have something like main()?

Tags: verilog

I understand that modules are essentially like c++ functions. However, I didn't find something like a main() section that calls those functions. How does it work without a main() section?

Comment: There is no "start"; it all happens at once.

Comment: What is your goal with Verilog? Coding for synthesis is different than testbench coding.

Comment: The closest thing to a main() would be the outermost top layer module, and it can be named anything you like is not limited to Start or main() or entry or anything like that.  Within that module you will see the other modules referenced, similar to calling other functions from main().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trying to find (or conceptually force) a main() equivalent in HDL is the wrong way to go about learning HDL -- it will prevent you from making progress. For synthesisable descriptions you need to make the leap from sequential thinking (one instruction running after another) to "parallel" thinking (*everything* is running *all* the time). Mentally, look at your code from left to right instead of top to bottom, and you may realize that the concept of main() isn't all that meaningful.

In HDL, we don't "call" functions, we instantiate modules and connect their ports to nets; again, you'll need to change your mental view of the process.

Once you get it, it all becomes much smoother...

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the normal use of Verilog is modeling/describing circuits. When you apply power, all the circuits start to run, so you need to write your reset logic to get each piece into a stable, usable operating state. Typically you'll include a reset line and do your initialization in response to that.

Answer (score 2):

Verilog has `initial` blocks are kinda like `main()` in C. These are lists of statements that are scheduled to run from time 0. Verilog can have multiple `initial` blocks though, that are executed concurrently.

`always` blocks will also work as `main()` if they've an empty sensitivity list:

```
always begin // no sensitivity list
   s = 4;
   #10;      // delay statements, or sim will infinite loop
   s = 8;
   #10;
end
```

Comment: What if you don't instantiate a module inside these blocks. Does it still get run?

Comment: They do, if their inputs are sensitive to any values that are twiddled.